# Promise перезапуск функции

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Начал изучать Promise, и столкнулся с некоторым недопониманием. У меня есть основная функция, где выполняются все действия. В переменную `wait` сохраняется результат промиса который относится к модулю puppeter: `await page.waitForSelection('CSSselector');` (в документации написано, что если он не находит селектор, то возвращает null). Далее я проверяю, `wait === null`, если условие выполняется, то запускается await Promise.all([page.waitForNavigation()]); и возвращаю `resolve('text');`. И теперь главное, в условии `else` я хочу вывести в консоль `error` надпись и снова проверить является ли `wait === null` и так, пока условие не выполнится.

```
let wait = await page.waitForSelection('CSSselector');
await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    if (wait === null) {
        await Promise.all([page.waitForNavigation()]);
        resolve('text')
    { else {
        console.log('error');
    }
}
```

Comment: @Vasily простой ретрай судя по всему.

Comment: @Vasily написал

Comment: @Malyuga, все равно непонятно, что за `promise`, зачем создавать `new Promise`, что за переменная `wait`?

Comment: @Grundy наверное не стоило его добавлять. Этот `promise` является методом модуля, поэтому я не стал особо акцентировать на этом внимание. `wait` - это переменная объявленная ранее в основной функции, как и `new Promise`.

Comment: @Malyuga, все еще непонятно, что у тебя есть сейчас, и как это сейчас работает,  и что именно ты хочешь поменять.

Comment: @Grundy, я изменил вопрос, более подробно описал, что хотел. Может станет яснее.

Comment: смущает _я хочу вывести в консоль error надпись и снова проверить является ли wait === null_ данная строка, так как ты можешь сколько угодно проверять `wait === null`, но если значение `wait` уже присвоено - он не изменится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С текущим кодом то, что ты хочешь сделать, не имеет смысла, потому что `wait` - это **результат** `promise`, следовательно он больше не изменит значение.

Если требуется заново присвоить переменной `wait` результат `await page.waitForSelection('CSSselector')`, то напрашивается обычный цикл, внутри асинхронной функции

```
async function fun(){
    for(let wait = await page.waitForSelection('CSSselector'); wait != null;wait = await page.waitForSelection('CSSselector')){
        console.log('error');
    }
    await page.waitForNavigation();// нет нужды в `.all` - потому что в массиве всего один элемент.
    return 'text';
}
```